# How to restore inapp purchase product properly in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

I have both Non-Consumable and Auto-Renewable Subscription in my product list. So when i try to restore purchases, I get all the purchases made. Now what should be the approach when restoring the purchase.

In my case i have two product that charges monthly and yearly and one that is non-consumable and gives lifetime access. So while testing, i made several transactions. But when restoring, i noticed i get all the purchased transactions list from which i need to restore a valid product for the user. So how do i know which item to restore?

From the docs, i found a way to verify a subscription and verify a product. But from my response i can see, i have both monthly and lifetime product that is valid for restoring. What should i do here?

**This is my code**

```
    @IBAction func restoreButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            //        SubscriptionService.shared.restorePurchases()
            if self.premium != nil {
                // contact alert
                self.showActionSheet(title: "Contact us", message: "Tell us your query at \(Settings.requestEmail)", email: Settings.requestEmail)
                return
            }

            notificationShown = false
            hud.show(in: self.view)

    //        let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .sandbox, sharedSecret: Payment.sharedSecret)

            SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases(atomically: true) { results in
                for purchase in results.restoredPurchases {
                    print("//////////////////////")
                    print(purchase.productId)
                    print("Original Transaction Date: \((purchase.originalTransaction?.transactionDate)!)")
                    print("Original Transaction State: \((purchase.originalTransaction?.transactionState)!)")
                    print("Transaction Date: \((purchase.transaction.transactionDate)!)")
                    print("Transaction State: \((purchase.transaction.transactionState))")
                    print("//////////////////////")

                    if purchase.productId == Payment.lifetime {
                        SubscriptionService.shared.verifyPurchase(productId: purchase.productId, transactionDate: purchase.originalTransaction?.transactionDate, completion: { (success) in
                            self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 3.0)
                            if success {
                                Premium().check().done { premium in
                                    self.premium = premium
                                    self.initiatePremiumView()
                                    self.initPurchaseButton()
                                }
                            } else {
                                if self.notificationShown == false {
                                    self.showNotification(title: "No item to restore", buttonTitle: "", type: .failure)
                                    self.notificationShown = true
                                }
                            }
                            if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        SubscriptionService.shared.verifySubscription(productId: purchase.productId, transactionDate: purchase.originalTransaction?.transactionDate, completion: { (success) in
                            self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 3.0)
                            if success {
                                Premium().check().done { premium in
                                    self.premium = premium
                                    self.initiatePremiumView()
                                    self.initPurchaseButton()
                                    }.catch { _ in }
                            } else {
                                if self.notificationShown == false {
                                    self.showNotification(title: "No item to restore", buttonTitle: "", type: .failure)
                                    self.notificationShown = true
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                        // Deliver content from server, then:
                        SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
                    }
                }


            }
            //            self.showAlert(self.alertForRestorePurchases(results))
        }

func verifySubscription(productId: String, transactionDate: Date?, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .sandbox, sharedSecret: Payment.sharedSecret)

        SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator, forceRefresh: false) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let receipt):
//                print(receipt.count)
                if receipt.count > 0 {
                    let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifySubscription(
                        ofType: .autoRenewable, // or .nonRenewing (see below)
                        productId: productId,
                        inReceipt: receipt)

                    switch purchaseResult {
                    case .purchased(let expiryDate, let items):
                        // give premium access
                        let premium = Premium(hasFullAccess: true, subscribedProduct: productId, expires: expiryDate, purchaseDate: transactionDate)
                        premium.giveFullAccess().done { result in
                            // show full access Dialog
                            completion(true)
                            }.catch { error in
                                // give error msg
                                completion(false)
//                                print("hell no")
                        }
//                        print("\(productId) is valid until \(expiryDate)\n\n")
                    case .expired(let expiryDate, let items):
                        // remove premium access
                        completion(false)
                        Premium().removePremiumAccess().done {_ in }.catch {_ in }
//                        print("\(productId) is expired since \(expiryDate)\n\n")
                    case .notPurchased:
                        // remove premium access
                        completion(false)
                        Premium().removePremiumAccess().done {_ in }.catch {_ in }
//                        print("The user has never purchased \(productId)")
                    }
                }
            //                print("Verify receipt success: \(receipt)")
            case .error(let error):
                print("Verify receipt failed: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func verifyPurchase(productId: String, transactionDate: Date?, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .sandbox, sharedSecret: Payment.sharedSecret)

        SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator, forceRefresh: false) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let receipt):
                if receipt.count > 0 {
                    let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifyPurchase(
                        productId: productId,
                        inReceipt: receipt)

                    switch purchaseResult {
                    case .purchased(let receiptItem):
                        let premium = Premium(hasFullAccess: true, subscribedProduct: productId, expires: nil, purchaseDate: transactionDate)
                        premium.giveFullAccess().done { result in
                            // show full access Dialog
                            completion(true)
                            }.catch { error in
                                // give error msg
                                completion(false)
//                                print("hell no")
                        }
//                        print("\(productId) is purchased: \(receiptItem)")
                    case .notPurchased:
                        completion(false)
                        Premium().removePremiumAccess().done {_ in }.catch {_ in }
                    }                    
                }
            //                print("Verify receipt success: \(receipt)")
            case .error(let error):
                print("Verify receipt failed: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Full Purchased product list when restoring: **

```
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 13:32:35 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 06:39:38 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 13:17:35 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 09:35:03 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 06:29:08 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-25 07:10:37 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 09:09:36 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-25 07:20:37 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 10:52:29 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: yearly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:35 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 09:30:01 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: yearly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:17:35 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 09:14:36 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 13:22:35 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 13:27:35 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 06:44:38 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 06:34:38 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-25 07:25:37 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 06:17:10 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 06:22:55 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 09:25:01 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-25 07:30:37 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 10:31:38 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: lifetime
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 11:06:13 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-25 09:23:14 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-24 09:20:01 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-25 07:05:37 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
Product Id: monthly
Original Transaction Date: 2019-04-23 12:14:36 +0000
Original Transaction State: purchased
Transaction Date: 2019-04-25 07:15:37 +0000
Transaction State: restored
//////////////////////
```

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58399614/11161030

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the active subscription sorted from latest and unlock them if it's active. **It's depend on your subscription logic by the way**.

> In my case, I check for following order.
>
> a) If there is a lifetime plan purchased, it will be un-locked for
>   lifetime.
>
> b) If no lifetime purchased, then will check for subscription in a
>   sorted purchase list and find out if there any subscription active and
>   unlock it if exist.

Also, I check for any unfinished purchase, then unlock content and mark it finished after unlock.

Comment: How do you unlock for a lifetime? I mean, what if a user deletes the app and re-installs it? IAP does not give you the receipt for this, isn't it?